# Fast way to download a video from an URL

Tags: ios, web-browsing

Is there an easy way to download a video from an URL to the device or to your Dropbox?

The only way I have managed to do that is using Mercury: manually copying the URL, going to the download manager and then pasting the URL there. Then, from Mercury I can save it to my camera roll or upload it to Dropbox.

Is there an easier way of doing this? Any way that doesn't involve copy/paste, either using Mercury or any other browse?

Comment: *Any* URL or from a specific video site?

Comment: Any random URL with a video (specifically, I wanted to download my own mail attachment videos, which have their own URL within Gmail).

Comment: If you want to download from Google mail, the app should be able to login on a website as well. Might be a though call. You may get better results if you word your question to focus more on the specific problem (aka automatically download videos from within Google Mail) and be more open on the solution (maybe a generic video downloader is not the easiest way to solve the problem).

Comment: @patrix: I don't understand what you are suggesting. I open Gmail in Safair, and then I open the video from Gmail. It's exactly the same as opening any video URL: Safari plays it in full screen, but does not let you download it, nor send it to any other file-accepting app like Dropbox.

Comment: If the videos are attached to your emails, any application (like a downloader) accessing these videos needs to log into your Gmail account to do so.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In addition to fiddling around in *Mercury Browser*:

I found a collection of ugly-looking spammy apps: [Video Downloader](http://appstore.com/videodownloader). I tried the purple one by Appsneon, it seems to work fine.

It shows a download button on iOS video player overlay, when browsing through the app. This is more convenient than Mercury Browser's approach. I wish mainstream browsers would offer this option as well.

Answer (score -1):

Downloading videos can be pretty hit or miss given the number of different video formats, players, server configurations, security settings, etc.

I usually start with [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) and [FlashGot](https://flashgot.net/) running in Firefox.  The old [Miro](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/20957/miro) app seems to only occasionally work.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I'm asking on iOS, not on OS X.

Answer (score -2):

http://www.boxmydownloads.com/dashboard/
Log in with your drop box account, paste the link to your video, and bam. It aslo works for PDF files, pictures, practically any type of website link.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions